# FFMpeg: scale and then overlay keeping overlay aspect ratio

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to scale a video, and then apply an overlay keeping the aspect ration of the same.

This adds the overlay, but it stretches it to the same aspect ratio of the video which is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex "scale=-1:1280:flags=bicubic,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h" -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -c:v mpeg4 -qscale:v 10 -c:a: copy out.mp4
```

Any help will be truly appreciated!

Comment: Unclear. I assume you want both the video and watermark to appear undistorted, right?

Answer (score 2):

Ended up solving it through `scale2ref`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:1280:flags=lanczos[bg];[1:v][bg]scale2ref=(250/180)*$ih/8/sar:$ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)-overlay_h" -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -c:v mpeg4 -qscale:v 10 -c:a: copy out.mp4`
```

Where 250 is the width of the overlay in pixels, and 180 its height.

This outputs a video of N:1280, with an overlay of 250x180 at the bottom-center of it.

Comment: Why two `$ih`? Was that a typo?